# SharePoint App: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app

I am getting the following error when I run the SharePoint app project via Visual studio debugger:

Anyone can help how to solve the Authorization issue? I am not sure what authorization I need since I have full control everywhere.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Source Error: 


Line 117:
Line 118:                context.Load(context.Site.RootWeb, r => r.Url);
Line 119:                context.ExecuteQuery();
Line 120:                var rootWebUrl = context.Site.RootWeb.Url;
Line 121:

Source File: C:\User1\IntranetDev\Intranet.MVC\Utilities\SearchUtil.cs    Line: 119 

Stack Trace: 


[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1399
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute() +37
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb) +615
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery() +47
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery() +89
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() +305
   Intranet.MVC.Utilities.SearchUtil.ExecuteQuery(ClientContext context, WindowsIdentity logonUserIdentity, Guid resultSourceId, String query, List`1 selectProperties, Int32 maxResults, String orderByProperty, SortDirection sortDirection) in C:\User1\IntranetDev\Intranet.MVC\Utilities\SearchUtil.cs:119
   Intranet.MVC.Utilities.SearchUtil.ExecuteQuery(ClientContext context, WindowsIdentity logonUserIdentity, String query, List`1 selectProperties, String orderByProperty, SortDirection sortDirection, Int32 maxResults) in C:\User1\IntranetDev\Intranet.MVC\Utilities\SearchUtil.cs:93
   Intranet.MVC.DataAccess.AdobeDataAccess.GetHomeModelFromCache(ClientContext context, WindowsIdentity logonUserIdentity, UrlHelper urlHelper, String path, Int32 languageId) in C:\User1\IntranetDev\Intranet.MVC\DataAccess\AdobeDataAccess.cs:122
   Intranet.MVC.DataAccess.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<GetHomeModel>b__0(String s) in C:\User1\IntranetDev\Intranet.MVC\DataAccess\AdobeDataAccess.cs:52
   Intranet.MVC.Cache.ExpiringMemoryCache.TryGetOrAdd(String key, Func`2 valueFactory, TValue& result, TimeSpan timeToLive, Boolean sliding, Boolean autoRefresh, Boolean unremovable, Boolean block) in C:\User1\IntranetDev\Intranet.MVC\Cache\ExpiringMemoryCache.cs:119
   Intranet.MVC.Cache.ExpiringMemoryCache.GetOrAdd(String key, Func`2 valueFactory, Nullable`1 timeToLive, Nullable`1 sliding, Nullable`1 autoRefresh, Boolean unremovable) in C:\User1\IntranetDev\Intranet.MVC\Cache\ExpiringMemoryCache.cs:285
   Intranet.MVC.DataAccess.AdobeDataAccess.GetHomeModel(ClientContext context) in C:\User1\IntranetDev\Intranet.MVC\DataAccess\AdobeDataAccess.cs:50
   Intranet.MVC.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\User1\IntranetDev\Intranet.MVC\Controllers\HomeController.cs:50
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9749233
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```